# Auto complete in `notepad++`

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++, jedit

I'm a great fan of [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b). Because of it's opensource and simplicity. I would like to help to make it more professional tool. In a recent days i have used [jedit](/questions/tagged/jedit) also a opensource editor. In this i was attracted to a feature called autocomplete popup. In it auto complete pop up all the entries are listed with sequence numbers like in below image so i can simply use numbers to insert the word instead of using navigation keys to locate the word which i want to insert. Moreover it is listing all the keywords of the present language that is more attractive. My question is there anyway i can achieve this in [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b)...??

[image]

Comment: Go to the official site: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: Well, why don't you just use jEdit then? :-) It is much better than N++, multi-platform and has the feature you want to have. :-)

Comment: I get an autocomplete popup by pressing [ctrl]+[enter]. you should also find autocomplete in the settingsmenue.